# Delegar un dominio de nic.ar a un proyecto de railway

Tags: hosting, dns

Tengo un proyecto hosteado en [railway](https://railway.app). Y estoy teniendo un problema al delegar un dominio ya comprado en [nic.ar](https://nic.ar)

Compre el dominio en nic.ar, y en la parte de settings del servicio de railway tambien configure para que use el dominio que yo compre.

Ahora mi problema viene porque railway me da informacion de un parámetro CNAME que no entiendo a que se refiere, porque en el panel de nic.ar no me aparece este parametro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Alguien me podria orientar en como delegar este dominio?

Comment: Creo que tenés que cargar la IP de tu página en el DNS, ahí dónde dice **Host** y listo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes ubicar el apartado de registros DNS, allí debes poder registrar uno tipo "CNAME"

El proveedor de tu dominio debería de tenerlo (normalmente todos lo traen), y si no, lo que puedes hacer es conectar el dominio con Cloudflare y ver si por sus DNS conectas Railway.

Recuerda que Cloudflare es un CDN y actúa como un puente.